# Check if table contatins a sepecific value in one of the columns

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table with few calumns. What is the best way to check if one of the columns contatins a specific value?

Example:

```
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
|----------|----------|----------|
|  aaa     |    bbb   |    ccc   |
|  ddd     |    eee   |    fff   |
|  ggg     |    hhh   |    iii   |
```

For example, I want to check if the value "eee" exists in the table.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE [Column 1]='eee' OR [Column 2]='eee' OR [Column 3]='eee';`

But you should reconsider your database design, as such lookup isn't very usual - there should be a broken principle using this approach!

Comment: Thank you! I have a table of verbs. Each verb has four columns for each form (base, past, past participle and present participle). I want to check if a given verb (in one of the forms) exists in the database.   What do you suggest?

Comment: Isn't it straight forward from example?

Comment: Yes, but you've said that it isn't a good way, so maybe you have an idea to make it more efficient?

Comment: I said database design may not be good. But it's always your choice. I could, for example `CREATE TABLE verbs (Verb, Form, Person, Word); CREATE INDEX v_idx ON verbs(Word);` and then just `SELECT * FROM verbs WHERE Word = 'eee';`. But you must choose what is more effective, faster, smaller, ... for your application.